# Can I install a new version of GCC on an old Cygwin?

Tags: gcc, windows-7, cygwin, version

If I install an old version of Cygwin (1.7.11, on Windows 7), can I later update the C++ compiler and its libraries (GCC 8.x)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only if you compile it by yourself. 
Please note that currently latest version on cygwin has only a test version of gcc 7.3.x

In general you can not use a recent cygwin package with a old version of the cygwin1.dll as new functions are added continuosly

https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/ov-new.html#ov-new2.10

and package using them directly or through libraries will not work on previous version of the cygwin1.dll.

It is not clear to me why you want to use a old cygwin1.dll and looking for not available yet compiler package.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Using an old cygwin version is not my choice, and looking for the latest compiler is to use C++17 features.

Comment: gcc 7.3 has preliminary coverage of `-std=c++17 or -std=c++1z` https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.3.0/gcc/Standards.html#C_002b_002b-Language

Comment: Cygwin-1.7.11 is 6 years old. https://sourceware.org/ml/cygwin-announce/2012-02/msg00041.html . Whoever approved it should update the list. Or are they running W7 of 2012 without updates ?

Comment: Building gcc on an obsolete cygwin is more trouble than it's worth.  On current cygwin,  all dependencies are sufficiently up to date that you can  build any gcc version without rebuilding dependencies which aren't straightforward as on linux